# FindOneAndUpdate is updating the variable, but not the database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an application where if the user has not completed training then the user should complete the training. After the training has been completed, the User collection, trainingCompleted field should change from false to true. With this code, when console.log(updatedUser), the results change from false to true, but the actual MongoDB database viewed in MongoDB Compass doesn't change?

I have tried using just updateOne, but this didn’t work either. I have tried using .save(), but this didn't do anything either.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    trainingComplete: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    topScore: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


app.put("/users/:username", async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let { username } = req.params;
        console.log(username);
        let updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
           { username: username },
           { $set: { trainingComplete: true } }, // Update trainingComplete to true
            { new: true },
        );
        //await updatedUser.save();
        console.log("UpdatedUser:", updatedUser);
        if (!updatedUser) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
        }
        res.json({ message: "Training status updated successfully", updatedUser });
        console.log("Updated Successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating training status: ", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});

const handleConfirm = async () => {
        try {
            let userRating = Math.max(selectedRating);
            console.log("UserRating", userRating);

            const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.0.189:3000/patients/${patientID}`);

            if (response.ok) {
                const { patientData, maxNumber } = await response.json();
                console.log("Patient Data:", patientData);
                console.log("Maximum Number:", maxNumber);

              if (userRating === maxNumber) {
                console.log("Correct");
                setRatingCorrect(true);
                const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem("username");
                console.log("Username", username);
                // Update the trainingComplete field for the logged-in user
                await fetch(`http://192.168.0.189:3000/users/${username}`, {
                    method: "put",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ trainingComplete: true }),
                });
                navigation.navigate("Profile");
                } else {
                    console.log("Incorrect");
                    setRatingCorrect(false);
                }

                setConfirmPressed(true);
            } else {
                console.error("Failed to fetch patient data:", response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error updating lesion_GS:", error);
        }
    };`
```

Comment: The code looks OK. Why do you think it didn't work? How did you check your db?

Comment: Sometimes with compass you need to hit the 'REFRESH' button or run a query and hit 'FIND'. The only other possibility is you are querying a different database from the one you are updating.

Comment: @jQueeny - This worked alongside the suggestions made by Sagnik, not sure if there is a better way because this makes the app not self-efficient???

Comment: @Ela I'm glad you got it working but the answer provided by Sagnik below adds nothing of value to your problem and was probably generated by ChatGPT. Passing an empty body in the put request would have made no difference to your code because you were not using the body value for anything anyway such as `{ $set: { trainingComplete: req.body.trainingComplete} }`. I think your problem was that your code worked perfectly fine and it saved to the database but with compass it doesn't refresh your current viewed query, you have to manually refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with the way you are sending the request to update the trainingComplete field in your MongoDB database. In your fetch request, you are sending a JSON body with the key trainingComplete, but in your server code, you are trying to update the field using $set: { trainingComplete: true }. This could be causing the update to fail.

Please refer to this code:

```
 await fetch(`http://192.168.0.189:3000/users/${username}`, {
        method: "put",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({}), // Empty body since you are not sending any specific data
    });
```

And in your server code, you can keep the $set as it is:

```
let updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { username: username },
    { $set: { trainingComplete: true } },
    { new: true },
);
```

Try making this adjustment and see if it resolves the issue, additionally, you can check the response from the server to see if there are any error messages or if the update is successful. You can log the response in your frontend code like this:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.0.189:3000/users/${username}`, {
    method: "put",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
});

if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("Update successful:", data);
} else {
    console.error("Update failed:", response.statusText);
}
```

This way, you can get more information about what might be going wrong in the update process.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?